# how to write name of the app under icon

Tags: android, android-layout, homescreen

I have created a launcher app which acts as the homescreen and there are many icons in it, each representing a different  app. I want to know how can I display name of the each app under these icon.
Here is the class which shows the icons:

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.seniorDesign.main.project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        //imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250,200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.phone, R.drawable.calendar, R.drawable.calculator,
            R.drawable.gallery, R.drawable.browser, R.drawable.email, 
            R.drawable.map, R.drawable.sms, R.drawable.camera, R.drawable.contacts,
            R.drawable.notepad_icon
            };
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Use `TextView` usial text view for each icon.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout for each item with image and text. Set this layout to items of your list or gridview. You can map your images with text names. So in getView you can set both text and image for every item.

Answer (score 0):

Chceck this article:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_example

it is related to `ListView`'s, but you can use very similar approach for your `GridView`. Read the whole article about lists and its performance for explanation how it all works.

Briefly, you need to inflate LinearLayout with vertical orientation and `ImageView` and `TextView` in it. Some inspiration:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.text.setText(names[position]);
    holder.image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return rowView;
}
```